# How do you create an SArray/MArray with changed units?

Tags: arrays, julia

I have a vector `u` and a number `t` with Unitful units, and I want `du` to have the units of `typeof(oneunit(u)/oneunit(t))`. I want to find a single generic line of code which constructs an `SArray` or `MArray` output which matches the input. There are a few cases which I have tried:

1. Obviously `copy(u)` doesn't match the units.
2. `u/oneunit(t)` and `u./oneunit(t)` both create `SArray`s, even when `u <: MArray`.
3. `similar` always creates a mutable type, so it always creates an `MArray`

Do I need to directly use the constructor (which would be a pain because it would add an odd branch to an otherwise generic code, but it's fine if that's the answer)?

## Edit

Example that a simple convert does not work with `MArray`s

```
u = @MArray [1u"g",2u"g",3u"g"]
t = 1u"s"
convert(typeof(u),u/t)

DimensionError: g and 1.0 g s^-1 are not dimensionally compatible.
```

While `similar` is hopeless:

```
u = @SArray [1u"g",2u"g",3u"g"]
similar(u)


3-element MVector{3,Quantity{Int64, Dimensions:{}, Units:{g}}}:
  72559480 g
 581132080 g
     29791 g
```

Answer (score 2):

How is:

```
static_similar(s, v) = 
  ( isimmutable(s) ? StaticArrays.mutable_similar_type : 
                     StaticArrays.default_similar_type)(eltype(v), 
                       Size(s), StaticArrays.length_val(s) )(v)
```

Giving:

```
julia> u = @MArray [1u"g",2u"g",3u"g"];

julia> s = @SArray [1u"g",2u"g",3u"g"];

julia> static_similar(u,u./oneunit(t))
3-element SVector{3,Quantity{Float64, Dimensions:{ ^-1}, Units:{g s^-1}}}:
 1.0 g s^-1
 2.0 g s^-1
 3.0 g s^-1

julia> static_similar(s,s./oneunit(t))
3-element MVector{3,Quantity{Float64, Dimensions:{ ^-1}, Units:{g s^-1}}}:
 1.0 g s^-1
 2.0 g s^-1
 3.0 g s^-1
```

The relevant functions are defined in `StaticArrays/src/abstractarray.jl`. Especially, note comment: https://github.com/JuliaArrays/StaticArrays.jl/blob/715fefe58bef7ef1d9b2e693d3468d4fd585e11f/src/abstractarray.jl#L60-L62

Comment: The function `static_similar` should probably be made @inline / @pure and maybe split into two functions to make the optimizations work best

Answer (score 1):

Great question!

Basically, as a static arrays user I always use `SArray` and a function programming approach to them. (When I need to manage memory I can use `Array{SArray{...}}` or whatever, and replace elements of the outer `Array`).

Probably not the answer you are looking for but I'd tend to chill out about the fact that operations return `SArray` and just learn to replace `SArray`s in their entirety. In most cases this is faster than fiddling with `MArray` because LLVM naturally invokes SIMD instructions for stack variables while the heap-allocated `MArray` operations do not.

Was it your expectation that operations like division would preserve the ability (or not) to mutate?

EDIT: yes, using the constructor or `convert` is totally a viable approach.

Comment: That won't work because the user is choosing a type for a specific reason and I need to be able to respect that. The real issue is that the type is a `SArray{SArray}` or `MArray{SArray}`. Changing the types either way breaks the algorithm because it expects that types aren't randomly changed from immutable to mutable and vice versa.

Comment: I updated the OP to show that a simple `convert` does not work. Maybe there's a fancier version that's required to pull the type without the parameters.